# manual Spring-data-rest Converters

Tags: converters, spring-data-rest

Could you recomendme a tutorial about converters of spring-data-rest? I've stuck one week in this issue and I read a lot of post and little manuals about it but I still don't knowing how it works or how to configure one

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, it’s not a tutorial, but it does provide an accessible and detailed introduction into Spring Data, including the Spring Data REST stuff. I wouldn't normally advertise books, but this one helped me a lot.

Spring Data. Modern Data Access for Enterprise Java.
By Mark Pollack, Oliver Gierke, Thomas Risberg, Jon Brisbin, Michael Hunger.
Publisher: O'Reilly Media

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024767.do